# Remote data science internship

Tags: job-search, hiring-process, internship

I am pursuing my Ph.D. in Data Science. I am looking for a summer internship to gain industry experience. I don't see any internship opportunities in my area. It's just a small college town. Currently, I am not in the position to relocate due to my family issues. Is there any possibility to find internships where I can work from home? I sincerely appreciate your suggestions!

Comment: Well... have you at least searched or googled? What have you found so far? Surely there is a possibility to find one, as long as you look for it

Comment: @DarkCygnus I searched for it. But, I don't see anything like remote!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Is there any possibility to find internships where I can work from home?

Remote internships are extremely rare to find, because typically interns are similar to entry-level employees that benefit from face to face interaction and adhoc training. If you really cannot locate and your town is just a college town, consider working for the university you attend.

Comment: I appreciate your thoughts!